# Flutter Samsung device autofill is not working for the first Time

Tags: flutter

I am using the auto fill  for sign in

I am using the below  code it is working for the other device only for the samsung  device   It is not working for the first time  any suggestion will appreciated .

```dart
            AutofillGroup(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.email]),
                  TextFormField(autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password]),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Elevated Button", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      TextInput.finishAutofillContext(shouldSave: true);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Since the error only occurs from some device that will be hard to test. Provide the error log/console, might help others to help